# Sum every nth points

Tags: r, sum, apply

I have a vector and I need to sum every `n` numbers and return the results. This is the way I plan on doing it currently. Any better way to do this?

```
v = 1:100
n = 10
sidx = seq.int(from=1, to=length(v), by=n)
eidx = c((sidx-1)[2:length(sidx)], length(v))
thesum = sapply(1:length(sidx), function(i) sum(v[sidx[i]:eidx[i]]))
```

This gives:

```
thesum
 [1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
unname(tapply(v, (seq_along(v)-1) %/% n, sum))
# [1] 55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

Answer (score 21):

#### UPDATE:

If you want to sum **every n consecutive numbers** use `colSums`
If you want to sum **every nth** number use `rowSums`

as per Josh's comment, this will only work if `n` divides `length(v)` nicely.

```
rowSums(matrix(v, nrow=n))
 [1] 460 470 480 490 500 510 520 530 540 550

colSums(matrix(v, nrow=n))
 [1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

---

Comment: Only works if `length(v)` is evenly divisible by `n`. Otherwise vector recycling will bite you. (See e.g. `v <- 1:3; n <- 2; matrix(v, nrow=n)`.)

Comment: Will work only if `matrix(..., byrow=TRUE)`, hence @Andrie answer where he uses `colSums`and not `rowSums`.

Comment: @plannapus, it wasnt clear if OP wanted every n-consecutive or every nth number.

Comment: If it is every `nth` number, I'd say just 550 is the answer. 10th, 20th etc.. Not 1, 11..., 2, 12 ... etc..

Comment: @Arun, well where do you start counting n numbers?

Comment: I understand every nth number of 1:100 as every 10th number: 10, 20, 30, ..., 100. That sums to 550, the earlier answers of both Andrie and Josh.

Answer (score 13):

### Update

The olde version don't work. Here a ne awnser that use `rep` to create the grouping factor. No need to use `cut`:

```
n <- 5 
vv <- sample(1:1000,100)
seqs <- seq_along(vv)
tapply(vv,rep(seqs,each=n)[seqs],FUN=sum)
```

---

You can use `tapply`

```
tapply(1:100,cut(1:100,10),FUN=sum)
```

or to get a list

```
by(1:100,cut(1:100,10),FUN=sum)
```

**EDIT**

In case you have `1:92`, you can replace your cut by this :

```
cut(1:92,seq(1,92,10),include.lowest=T)
```

Comment: I can see why you like the answer, but this would not work for a random vector of numbers where you want to sum up every n elements, would it?

Comment: @MaxM You are right. I will udpate my answer to include a new version.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to convert your vector to a matric then take the column sums:

```
colSums(matrix(v, nrow=n))
[1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

---

Just be careful: this implicitly assumes that your input vector can in fact be reshaped to a matrix. If it can't, R will recycle elements of your vector to complete the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

```
v <- 1:100

n <- 10

cutpoints <- seq( 1 , length( v ) , by = n )

categories <- findInterval( 1:length( v ) , cutpoints )

tapply( v , categories , sum )
```

Comment: (+1) this gives the right result as well, even if v = 1:92 and n = 10.

Answer (score 3):

I will add one more way of doing it without any function from `apply` family

```
v <- 1:100
n <- 10

diff(c(0, cumsum(v)[slice.index(v, 1)%%n == 0]))
##  [1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

Comment: Just be aware that when, e.g. `v <- 1:99`, this will not include the sum of the final 9 numbers (which might or might not be OK).

Comment: `nv = length(v); i = c(seq_len(nv %/% n) * n, if (nv %% n) nv else NULL)` and then `diff(c(0, cumsum(v)[i]))` seems to get the edge cases of `length(v) == 0` and `length(v) %% n != 0`.

Comment: `slice.index(v, 1)` could be replaced with just `v`, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the main variants offered so far

```
f0 <- function(v, n) {
    sidx = seq.int(from=1, to=length(v), by=n)
    eidx = c((sidx-1)[2:length(sidx)], length(v))
    sapply(1:length(sidx), function(i) sum(v[sidx[i]:eidx[i]]))
}

f1 <- function(v, n, na.rm=TRUE) {    # 'tapply'
    unname(tapply(v, (seq_along(v)-1) %/% n, sum, na.rm=na.rm))
}

f2 <- function(v, n, na.rm=TRUE) {    # 'matrix'
    nv <- length(v)
    if (nv %% n)
        v[ceiling(nv / n) * n] <- NA
    colSums(matrix(v, n), na.rm=na.rm)
}

f3 <- function(v, n) {                # 'cumsum'
    nv = length(v)
    i <- c(seq_len(nv %/% n) * n, if (nv %% n) nv else NULL)
    diff(c(0L, cumsum(v)[i]))
}
```

Basic test cases might be

```
v = list(1:4, 1:5, c(NA, 2:4), integer())
n = 2
```

`f0` fails with the final test, but this could probably be fixed

```
> f0(integer(), n)
Error in sidx[i]:eidx[i] : NA/NaN argument
```

The cumsum approach `f3` is subject to rounding error, and the presence of an NA early in `v` 'poisons' later results

```
> f3(c(NA, 2:4), n)
[1] NA NA
```

In terms of performance, the original solution is not bad

```
> library(rbenchmark)
> cols <- c("test", "elapsed", "relative")
> v <- 1:100; n <- 10
> benchmark(f0(v, n), f1(v, n), f2(v, n), f3(v, n),
+           columns=cols)
      test elapsed relative
1 f0(v, n)   0.012     3.00
2 f1(v, n)   0.065    16.25
3 f2(v, n)   0.004     1.00
4 f3(v, n)   0.004     1.00
```

but the matrix solution `f2` seems to be both fast and flexible (e.g., adjusting the handling of that trailing chunk of fewer than `n` elements)

```
> v <- runif(1e6); n <- 10
> benchmark(f0(v, n), f2(v, n), f3(v, n), columns=cols, replications=10)
      test elapsed relative
1 f0(v, n)   5.804   34.141
2 f2(v, n)   0.170    1.000
3 f3(v, n)   0.251    1.476
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `rollapply` from `zoo`:

```
rollapply(v, width=n, FUN=sum, by=n)
# [1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

And in case `length(v)` is not a multiple of `n`:

```
v <- 1:92

rollapply(v, width=n, FUN=sum, by=n, partial=T, align="left")
# [1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 183
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but I don't see a `rowsum()` answer yet. `rowsum()` is proven more efficient than `tapply()` and I think it would also be very efficient relative to a few of the other responses as well.

```
rowsum(v, rep(seq_len(length(v)/n), each=n))[,1]
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
# 55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

Using @Josh O'Brien's grouping technique would likely improve efficiency even more.

```
rowsum(v, (seq_along(v)-1) %/% n)[,1]
#  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
# 55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

Simply wrap in `unname()` to drop the group names.